# Writing 'Map' Using Callbacks in custom 'Each' - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

I have each() that iterates through a collection and performs a function on it.

```
_['each'] = function(collection, iterator) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection) === false && typeof(collection) === 
'object') {
    var values = Object.values(collection);
    var keys = Object.keys(collection);
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      iterator(values[i], keys[i], collection, i);
    }    
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  }
}
```

I want to write map() that takes the results and returns a new array. If I had to use a callback to make use of the each() function, I'm stuck on how to pull those values out. But assuming map() takes two parameters, a collection and the function for the iterator, I'm not sure how I would even access 'i' or any other value as they would be undefined. Should each() have a third parameter to take another callback to adding values into a collection?

Comment: Is there a reason you are rewriting Array.forEach() and Array.map() ? Since .forEach() + desctructuring is almost the same as your each that works on objects. I do not understand the question though. You should inject the same things into iterator, including the index, as you do in the for loops. PS: Your function will throw when the collection is `null`, since `Array.isArray(null) === false && typeof(null) === 
'object')` === true, but `Object.values(null)` will throw.

Comment: I imagine that "implement `forEach` for scratch", "implement `map` from scratch" are OK programming exercises.

Comment: True, I would just expect different structure if this is excercise. Just asking because I often see people that are learning JS do this before they learn about the existence of array methods.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an empty array, call `_.each` on the input collection, and write results to your output array. Something like

```
_['map'] = function(collection, iterator) {
   var result = [];

   var mapIterator = function(value, key, collection, i) {
      result[i] = iterator(value, key, collection, i);
   }

   _['each'](collection, mapIterator);
   return result;
}
```